# Infinite loading on conn.recv python socket

Tags: python, loops, sockets, connection

I'm currently trying to make a socket connection between a server and multiple clients in Python.
In short, I have a function that is used to test if the clients are still online or dead.

To do so, i'm sending a white space to the client, and if no exception occures, it's all good, and if there is an exception I'm deleting the client from the client list.
Everything works fine, except when the client is switching network (for exemple I switch from a 2GHz network, to the same network in 5GHz). Then, the conn.recv is creating an infinite loading because the client is not receiving the data that was sent in conn.send. As a precision, both of the network where I was connected works well separately. The only solution that I found for now is restarting the server when such an event occurs..

Here is the part of the code that doesn't work (server):

```
# Check for clients availability
def check_clients(self, UUID):
    invalid_conn = []
    print(f"(UUID: {UUID}) Checking for dead clients")
    
    if UUID not in self.all_connections: return False

    # Delete dead clients for specific user (UUID)
    self.socket.settimeout(2) # Also tried to set a timeout, doesn't work
    print('setting timeout')
    for i, conn in enumerate(self.all_connections[UUID]):
        try:
            print('sending blank cmd')
            conn.send(str.encode(' '))
            cwd = str(conn.recv(20480)) # This is the line that causes infinite loop
            print('got cwd:',cwd) # This is what we are excepting from the client
        except:
            print('appening invalid conn to list:',conn)
            invalid_conn.append(conn)
            continue
    print('removing timeout')
    self.socket.settimeout(None)

    for i in invalid_conn:
        client_id = self.all_connections[UUID].index(i)
        print(f'(UUID: {UUID}) Could not reach client on conn list, removing {self.all_addresses[UUID][client_id]}')
        del self.all_connections[UUID][client_id]
        del self.all_addresses[UUID][client_id]

    print(f"(UUID: {UUID}) Dead clients check finished")
    return
```

And here is the part of the client that should receive the server information:

```
# Receive commands from server
def receive_commands(self):
    while True:
        print("Listening for commands")
        output_str = None
        data = self.sock.recv(1024)
        print('data:',data)
        if len(data) > 0:
            try:
                cmd = data[:].decode("cp850")
                # Do such and such events with cmd, this is a shortened version for demo
                output_str = str(f'received: {cmd} from server', "cp850")
            except Exception as e:
                output_str = f"Command failed to execute: {str(e)}"

        if output_str == None:
            raise ConnectionError ("No response from server")
        else:
            self.print_output(output_str)
            print(f"Input command: {data[:].decode('cp850')}")
            print(f"Output -> {output_str}\n")

    self.sock.close()
    return
```

Please ask me if you need any more info, thank you for your help.

Comment: you set the timeout on `self.socket` but then you interact with `self.all_connections`, perhaps you need to set the timeout on the items in `self.all_connections`?

Comment: Well, self.all_connections is a list of all the connected clients, it's not related to the socket it's just the list of conn you know.